# multer, npm - originalname is garbled:(

Tags: node.js, encoding, multer

I'm creating a video upload API in Node.js. To upload it, I have to handle the multipart request, so I'm using npm library "multer".

Try to send a video file(like below) in Postman.

> テスト_test.mp4

"テスト" is some Japanese character. And when posting that, the result is:

```
console.log(req.file.originalname)
=> ƹ�(_test.mp4
```

I want

> originalname=>テスト_test.mp4

not

> originalname=>ƹ�(_test.mp4

Implementation:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const request = require('request')

const multer = require('multer')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "some/dest/dir")
  }
})

var upload = multer({
  storage: storage
}).single("file")
router.use(upload)

router.post("/videos", functinon(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.file.originalname)
})
```

Postman:

```
・request header Content-Type: multipart/form-data 
・request body file:テスト_test.mp4
```

Does anybody have ideas?

Comment: Could you provide your implementation? Questions like "why it doesn't work?" are off-topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry, I added the implementation.